# Re-use Android layout

Tags: android, android-layout

i have an root_layout :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:weightSum="10">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/parentViewHolder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/spaceHolder"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:text="TEXT">
    </TextView>
```

Now i want, everytime i want to change the screen, that these layout is used and filled with an other declared layout.xml

I tried to use

```
    protected void Setup(int _layoutResourceId) 
{ 
    layoutResourceId = _layoutResourceId;
    FrameLayout holder = (FrameLayout) activity.findViewById(R.id.parentViewHolder);

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);    
    holder.addView(layoutInflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, null, false)); 
    activity.screen = this;
}
```

But this didn't work fine.Did anyone knows a nicer implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add a different layout to the `FrameLayout` from the layout that you posted, this is how you should do it:

```
protected void Setup(int _layoutResourceId) { 
    layoutResourceId = _layoutResourceId;
    FrameLayout holder = (FrameLayout) activity.findViewById(R.id.parentViewHolder);
    holder.removeAllViews();
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);    
    layoutInflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, holder, true)); 
    activity.screen = this;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for all my screens accept one.This screen seems to  work, but i cant see the @+id/spaceHolder element.is there a reason for?

Comment: @Kooki There is something special about that screen? Also try to modify the height of the *parentViewHolder* `FrameLayout` like this: `android:layout_height="0dp"` and see if this solves the problem.

Comment: sry i solved the problem.i had setontentView for another time later on, so i can't see the parent_layout :-) my fault!

Comment: Way to say exactly what I said :p

Comment: @Barak Not exactly the same:)

Answer (score 1):

You can reuse the layout like this:

First, implement a layout like described in your problem. For example, it's file name is root_layout.xml.

Then, if you want to use it in another view, simply add this to your xml file:

```
<include layout="@layout/root_layout"></include>
```

And root_layout will be inflated into another layout.

Notice that every attribute of root_layout is preserved. So pay attention on them.

Comment: He's not wanting to use the layout in another layout, he wants to swap views in the framelayout.

Comment: OK, I may misunderstand the problem. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say how it wasn't working, so I'll assume you are left with both views on the screen... you should use `removeAllViews()`.

Try this:

```
protected void Setup(int _layoutResourceId)  
{  
    layoutResourceId = _layoutResourceId; 
    FrameLayout holder = (FrameLayout) activity.findViewById(R.id.parentViewHolder); 
    holder.removeAllViews();  
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);     
    holder.addView(layoutInflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, null, false));  
    activity.screen = this; 
}
```